# Building proprietary software over haskell compiler

Tags: licensing, haskell

Is it perfectly legal to use GHC as base and build some commercial application over its top ? Are there such examples I can can interact with ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I intend to design some mathematical application which clubs graphics and symbolic processing. I want to know that if I use GHC, will it cause some legal problem in future.Any info will do.

Comment: Can you use GCC to create commercial applications? A compiler which enforced a license on its code would be taking "avoid success at all costs" a bit too literally, I think.

Comment: @Phoshi : sorry ..didn't understand this "avoid success at all costs" quote !!

Comment: Are you writing a Haskell application and compiling it with GHC, or writing a Haskell application that incorporates and uses the GHC code base? But since the GHC code is BSD licensed, neither should be a legal problem.

Comment: @Blackbird: It's a joking slogan of Haskell to try and avoid being useful. Obviously it isn't something they really take into account.

Comment: @delnan : I might need to use code base too..I am intending to seriously work on it and in coming times might need to modify GHC code base at places though its so beautifully written that its only a consideration now. I will write libraries on top of it as a start. Thanks for info on licensing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**([IANAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL))**

AFAIK by default GHC is linked with the [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) for integer arithmetics. And the library is licensed under LGPL, which requires that users of a program that uses the library can replace the library with a different one. This is hardly possible with GHC static builds and strong optimizations.

This problem is described in [tichet #601](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/601) and on GHC's wiki page [Replacing GMP: Bignum libraries, Licensing and Implementation](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReplacingGMPNotes). A [link at the end of the ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/601#comment:15) says that now you can select a native numeric library, when compiling GHC, thus avoiding the problem.

So be sure that whatever you build on top of GHC, you opt out of using GMP when compiling GHC. As long as you're using only BSD3 (or similar permissive licenses), there are very few restrictions you have to obey.